# How many 7-character passwords can be generated with...Stipulations?

Tags: probability, statistics

Characters can only be (a-z), (A-Z), and (0-9) w/stipulation that first character must be a lower case letter, the last character must be an upper case letter, and of the 5-characters in the middle there must be at-least ones digit (0-9).

How many 7-character passwords can be generated with the above stipulations?

Comment: Can you share your thoughts, and explain what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The number of ways to choose such a password is the number of ways to choose the first character, times the number of ways to choose the last character, times the number of ways to choose the 5 characters in the middle.  So, you must count these.

Counting the number of possibilities for the first and last digits should be no sweat.  As for the five in the middle: my hint to you is to remember that the number of ways to choose five characters, at least one of which is a digit, is given by
$$
(\text{total number of 5-character strings}) - (\text{number of 5-character strings with no digits}).
$$

Comment: (26)(52^5-10^5)(26)???

Comment: (26)((62^5)-(52^5))(26)

Comment: $52^5$ is the number of ways to make a five-character string using only A-Z and a-z, not the number of ways to make a five-character string using A-Z, a-z, and 0-9. And $10^5$ is the number of ways to make a five-character string using only 0-9 (i.e. containing ONLY digits), as opposed to containing NO digits.

Comment: I would say that your second answer seems reasonable, yes.

Comment: Thank u!...e-mail?...A couple more questions. I promise not to be a pain.

Comment: @Phil If you have more questions, please just ask them on this site. I'm happy to answer questions here when I have time... but that way, when I'm busy, there are others around to help.